# WebAudio API sampling rate

Tags: web-audio-api

Is it possible to specify the sampling rate (`sampleRate` attribute of the [`AudioContext`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioContext-section) object) for a real-time audio context?

For what I read, it is possible to specify the `sampleRate` for an [`OfflineAudioContext`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#OfflineAudioContext-section) object (the constructor takes 3 arguments, the last one being the sample rate), but the real-time `AudioContext` doesn't take any arguments.

I imagine is not possible, as probably that is defined by the browser itself, but maybe there's a way?

Comment: There is a library called Recorder.js that can be used with the webaudio API and from the look of it it allows you to change the sample rate of a recording. Maybe you can find your answer there. https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for. What I'd like is to be able to setup the `AudioContext` to a lower sample rate (say 22050Hz or 16kHz) to reduce the load on the CPU.

Comment: What I meant to say is it looks like the library inherently allows you to configure the AudioContext.sampleRate and I figure if the library lets you do it - you can probably do it. But then again maybe I'm misreading the code at the link. I'm still relatively new to development.

Comment: I looked at the [Recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/recorder.js) code, but it doesn't seem to set the sampleRate. It simply reads the `sampleRate` from the `AudioContext` and passes it to the worker that writes the output file.

Comment: I misinterpreted it then.

Comment: Here is a way to re-sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31366337/2715306

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this, other than setting the sampling rate of your sound card at the operating system level (not all i/o devices support this).

Answer (score 2):

An update.  The latest version of the spec now does allow you to specify the sample rate.  Use `new AudioContext({sampleRate: desiredRate})` to choose the desired sample rate.  The browser will take care of resampling everything to work with the actual sample rate of the audio hardware.  This is supported on every browser, except, perhaps, Safari.

Comment: I can confirm this, my browser allows a value from 3000 to 768000, which is insane... Can a cheap integrated soundcard really capture at 768000 Hz?

Comment: No a cheap integrated sound card probably can't do that.  But a fancy card or external device could.  I think that if the card isn't capable of such frequencies, the context will resample 768 kHz to what ever rate is supported by the sound card.