# How to set up sample rate using web audio API?

Tags: web-audio-api

I have blob type generated by webaudio API, but the file that is saved have to high sample rate.
How can I convert it to lower maybe something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext can help?
Here is some sample of code:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   /* HERE IS SOME CONVERTATION TO LOWER RATE */

    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append("randomname", bigBlob);
    xhr.open("POST",url,false);
    xhr.send(fd);

    xhr.onload=function(e) {
        alert(e.target.responseText);
    };
```

Comment: So you are recording sound using Web Audio API, and you want to convert to a lower sample rate before sending it to the server. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

- Create an OfflineAudioContext with the rate you want at the end, and the number of frames there will be at the end
- Create an AudioBuffer from your raw data buffer
- Create an AudioBufferSourceNode, set its buffer attribute to the AudioBuffer you just created, and connect this AudioBufferSourceNode to the destination of the OfflineAudioContext
- Start the AudioBufferSourceNode at 0
- Start the rendering

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to control the sample rate but here is a way to re-sample (up/down sampling)

```
function reSample(audioBuffer, targetSampleRate, onComplete) {
    var channel = audioBuffer.numberOfChannels;
    var samples = audioBuffer.length * targetSampleRate / audioBuffer.sampleRate;

    var offlineContext = new OfflineAudioContext(channel, samples, targetSampleRate);
    var bufferSource = offlineContext.createBufferSource();
    bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;

    bufferSource.connect(offlineContext.destination);
    bufferSource.start(0);
    offlineContext.startRendering().then(function(renderedBuffer){
        onComplete(renderedBuffer);
    })
}
```

Extracted from here:
https://github.com/notthetup/resampler